# The property update is only performed in the next update run

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a "update user name" component which takes in a name as a property. This component also has a save button and emits an update event if clicked.

The name is empty on page load because I have to fetch user in the parent component first. Unfortunately the child component will not update after fetching the user with its name. And when updating the name in the child component it renders the previous name.

I tried to reproduce the behaviour, if you want to have a playground this is the sandbox

https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-gagarin-e6kbz

My child component

```
<template>
  <div>
    <input v-model="currentName" placeholder="name">
    <button @click="resetCurrentName">Cancel</button>
    <button @click="update">Update</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      currentName: ""
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    // update current input to prop
    this.resetCurrentName();
  },
  methods: {
    resetCurrentName() {
      this.currentName = this.name;
    },
    update() {
      this.$emit("update", this.currentName);
      this.resetCurrentName();
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

and my parent component

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <UpdateName :name="name" @update="updateName"/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import UpdateName from "./components/UpdateName";

export default {
  components: {
    UpdateName
  },
  data() {
    return {
      user: null
    };
  },
  async mounted() {
    await console.log("fetching the user from the api");
    this.user = { name: "bar" };
  },
  computed: {
    name() {
      const user = this.user;

      if (!user) {
        return "";
      }

      return user.name;
    }
  },
  methods: {
    async updateName(newName) {
      await console.log("updating user name via api call");
      this.user.name = newName;
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

So basically I would have to force an prop update after fetching the user from the API. But Vue should do it by default. So I can't figure out what's wrong or missing here. How can I fix this behaviour?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things that you have to observe here:

1. Vue doesn't watch nested properties. To make it watch, use `$set` instead
2. When you call `this.resetCurrentName` in `updateName`, you are resetting the changes made in vue instance. Since, mounted isn't called on prop updates, it is causing the old `this.name` to be used instead of the new one. You can check the same in `console.log` s

Here is the link to working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/tender-payne-7ydb6

Comment: yes this works :) but unfortunately this won't update the initial state after fetching the user from the API ..

Comment: after loading the page I would expect the input field to have the value `bar`

Comment: so, on page load, you expect to see bar. If user changes anything and clicks update, you expect to see whatever they changed to, right? Also, when you say, after loading the page, do you mean reloading? Are you saving the data to back?

Comment: Would you want something like this? : https://codesandbox.io/s/tender-payne-7ydb6   Notice the watch in UpdateComponent. That is needed because mounted isn't called on prop update.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the link of the updated sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/pensive-ives-jex2e

```
   update() {
      this.$emit("update", this.currentName);
      this.resetCurrentName();
    }
```

Don't reset the name on updating.

Comment: thanks but it still won't update the initial state after fetching the user from the API :S

Comment: after loading the page I would expect the input field to have the value `bar`